# Move window to a adjacent virtual desktop in KDE

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

I am running kubuntu 16.04, in gnome I was able to move a window between adjacent workspaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (to move the window one desktop to the right)

Where are the settings for this shortcut on KDE?

This is my global keyboard settings, the options seem to be missing:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thank you **Mquinteiro** for pointing us to the shortcut. I am on KDE Neon (Plasma 5.9.2) and I found the shortcut in

```
Sustem Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KWin -> Window to Next Desktop
```

and it does what is says it does.

But this is still very limited. You cannot move the window directly to the virtual desktop you want; You can only iterate between the desktops until your window is moved to the desktop you intended.

I mean, here I can define a shortcut for **Window to Next desktop** but not for **moving Window to desktop at left** and **moving window to desktop bottom** and so on.

Comment: and what would be a proper key combination to do this be?

Answer (score 3):

Yo can define you own shortcuts.
Go to settings ->shorcuts -> global keyboard shortcuts and there select the kde component "system settings" seach for window to next screen and choose your shortcut.

Depending of the system / version it could be in diferent subsection of "Global keyboard shortcuts" I have it in "system settings" and in other computer in "KWin" section. So if you don't find it take a look in other places.

[System settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxjGP.png)

[search next screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPpv9.png)

Comment: `system settings` only has the following: `Halt Without Confirmation`, `Lock Screen`, `Log Out`, `Log Out Without Confirmation`, and `Reboot Without Confirmation`

Comment: @morgoth, is there I've edited the answer with two images.

Comment: I don't have that, I've updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: @morgoth look in kwin section instead "system settings"

Comment: It is under the "KDE Control Module"

Comment: @morgoth so the answer is search in "global keyboard shortcuts", it can be in different places.  I've modified the answer to reflect it.